# Returning an element and filtering inner elements to get their contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the selector I am trying to use in order to return the data below it.

```
$('.groupPopper').click(function(event){
    var name = $(this).index(".name").contents();
    alert(name);
});

<a class="groupPopper">
   [text class="name">Name here</a>
</a>
```

How do I return the text element by it's class, by clicking element 'a' in jquery? My example won't work..

Comment: If you read the docs, you'll see that `.index()` returns a number. Given your markup, it seems that you just need `$(this).text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you've posted under your jQuery is supposed to be HTML, this should work:

```
$('.groupPopper').click(function(event){
    var name = $(".name", this).text();
    alert(name);
});
```

Comment: dot . is missing before text()

Comment: @Adil thanks. You're the first person to notice that in 18 months :)

Comment: You are welcome @Rory McCrossan, I think it was trivial enough to be noticed as it solved the OP and even got accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3euyA/)

```
$('.groupPopper').click(function(event){
    var name = $(".name", this).text();
    alert(name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try using `.text()`

$('.groupPopper').click(function(event){
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    alert(name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To return a child by its class name, you can use `.find` in jQuery:

```
$('.groupPopper').click(function(event){
    var name = $(this).find(".name").text();
    alert(name);
});
```

Or if you have more than one child with this class, you can iterate them with `.each`:

```
$('.groupPopper').click(function(event){
    $(this).find(".name").each(function() {;
        var name = $(this).text();
        alert(name);
    });
});
```